# Installing Sencha Touch on Fedora

Tags: linux, extjs, fedora, sudo

I wanted to install Sencha Touch on Fedora. I was following [this tutorial on icodeya](http://www.icodeya.com/2012/12/installing-sencha-touch-201-on-ubuntu.html) but they're using Ubuntu, not Fedora, so I got a bit lost on this part:

```
sudo chown -R icodeya:www-data sencha-touch-2.0.1-gpl
```

I had this error:

> line 59: stderr.txt: Permission denied

Anybody know how to solve it? I mean, does the command differ on Fedora?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: it looks like you are not a member of group that can run sudo.

1. try to log in as root
2. go to appropriate dir
3. run `chown -R icodeya:www-data sencha-touch-2.0.1-gpl`

if i'm right (in fedora you have define useres that can tun sudo) it should be working.

wish you a luck!